# Artisan migrate in Laravel 5 throwing PDOException

Tags: laravel, pdo

I just created a fresh Laravel 5 application and wrote some migrations. Whenever I tried to run `php artisan migrate`, I encountered the following error

> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '
>     /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)

My database configuration is correct

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'), //I also tried 127.0.0.1
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mydb'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'myusername'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

I am using LAMP stack, could this be the problem for Laravel 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the database config (`database.php`) to this

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost, 
    'database'  => 'YOUR DB NAME',
    'username'  => 'YOUR DB USERNAME',
    'password'  => 'YOUR DB PASSWORD,
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

Or you can set the up the `.env` file

Every `Laravel` app now ships with a default `.env.example` file, which at the moment looks like this:

```
APP_ENV=local 
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString
DB_DATABASE=your_db_name
DB_USERNAME=your_username
DB_PASSWORD=your_db_password
```

In order to use this file, just copy it and name the copy (new file) `.env` and enter your database details.

The `.env` file should be in the root folder like `.env.example`.

Note:-  don't rename the `.env.example` file....always create a new `.env`

The `env('DB_DATABASE', 'default_value')` takes the value of `DB_DATABASE` from `.env` file if not found selects the default 'default_value'.

Answer (score 0):

Since the config is using `env()` you need to set the values in the `.env` file found in the root of your project. The values you are passing as the second parameter are defaults, which will only be used when the specific key is not found in the `.env` file. So the database portion of `.env` would look like this:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=myusername
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

You can read more on how Laravel handles enviroments in the [Configuration Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration).